# How to add wsse:Security, UsernameToken header to a SOAP request in ZSI, Python?

Tags: python, ws-security, zsi, usernametoken

Is there a way to add the wsse:Security, UsernameToken header to the SOAP requests in ZSI, Python? I searched on the web, but couldn't find an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After searching further, I'm convinced and planning to use suds, https://fedorahosted.org/suds/, which seems to be user-friendly, feature-rich, and provides classes and methods to add the UsernameToken to the SOAP header.

Suds Documentation on WS-Security: https://fedorahosted.org/suds/wiki/Documentation#WS-SECURITY

Comment: The documentation seems to have expired now. Is there any other link or example to the new googlers like me ?